# changing to jruby, get RuntimeError: Server handler (thin) not found

Tags: sinatra, jruby, thin

My app works fine in MRI 1.9.2-p290 and 1.9.3-p125, but when I change to jruby-1.7.0-preview1 I get the error discribed.  Here's the full error:

```
RuntimeError: Server handler (thin) not found.
  detect_rack_handler at /home/qry_dev/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1402
             run! at /home/qry_dev/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1293
           (root) at /home/qry_dev/Ruby/query_engine/query_webserver.rb:320
             load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017
           (root) at -e:1
```

(I tried jruby-1.6.6 already, same error.) 
The sinatra and thin gems (among others) are already installed.  In fact, other than jruby instead of mri, everything's the same.

Any ideas?  I've searched the web and seen this error, but it's usually for 3rd party tools, and nothing seems to apply.

EDIT: also tried installing thin (which I never had to do before) to linux itself via

```
sudo apt-get install thin
```

but still getting same error.

Comment: The output of `gem list` has `thin` as an entry?

Comment: yes, thin is installed; `gem list thin` returns `thin (1.3.1)`

Answer (score 2):

sinatra **1.3.2** (by default) checks only for mostly MRI compatible servers, see:
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/e111243e813ede1f0f4c6918d9a8cc029e776fc3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1514

*thin*, *mongrel* do not work on JRuby due native C code (although there's effort to make them use some "native" Java code on JRuby)

you have two options either adjust the set server while on JRuby e.g. something like:

```
set :server, %w[trinidad webrick] if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
```

or rackup your application with the given handler `rackup -s trinidad`

do not forget to `gem install trinidad` first (under JRuby)

Comment: Tried setting server to trinidad (after installing it, of course) got a bunch of messages like `WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/home/jenko/Ruby/lib/extensions.jar] from classloader hierarchy` and `SEVERE: Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/home/jenko/Ruby/lib/jna.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/]` among others.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with that without getting into more detail about your application - depends on how you're running JRuby as well. SO is best suited for 1 answer at a time, you might want to try a forum, IRC for getting step by step guidance (or post separate question with details about your app)

Comment: Concur.  Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `thin` server which `sinatra` will pickup automatically.
To install `thin` you can execute the following command

```
gem install thin
```